# Consultas ajax dependientes

Tags: jquery, ajax

Busco la manera de ejecutar una segunda consulta `ajax` de `jQuery` con un dato recuperado de la primera consulta, por ejemplo:

Ingreso el número de documento que quiero consultar y al hacer `click` en el botón, muestra el color guardado en base de datos para ese usuario.

```
$(".botonConsulta").click(function(){
  //Capturo el número de documento de un input
  var documento = $('.documento');

  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append('documento', documento);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(respuesta){
      //Muestro en pantalla el color guardado para ese usuario
      $('.colorSeleccionado').html(respuesta['color']);
    }
  })
}
```

Esta consulta muestra, digamos, el color "Verde"... Ahora, con ese color, necesito crear la segunda consulta `ajax` para traer todos los datos del color **Verde** de la tabla **colores**.

Intenté con `promise` pero muestra `false` en consola:

```
$(".botonConsulta").click(function(){
  //Capturo el número de documento de un input
  var documento = $('.documento');

  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append('documento', documento);

  var promesa = $.ajax({
    url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(respuesta){
      //Muestro en pantalla el color guardado para ese usuario
      $('.colorSeleccionado').html(respuesta['color']);
    }
  })
  $promesa.done(function(respuesta){
   var color= respuesta['color'];
   console.log(color) //Muestra en consola "Verde"

   var info = new FormData();
   info.append('color', color);

   $.ajax({
     url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
     method: 'POST',
     data: info,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(respuesta){
      console.log(respuesta) //Muestra en consola "False"
    }
  })
 });       
})
```

Cabe aclarar que aún no comprendo completamente el uso de `promise`, no se si lo estoy implementando bien.

Cómo puedo ejecutar el segundo `ajax` para que muestre los valores de la tabla **colores** con el color devuelto en la primera consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declaracion `new Promise()` y te falta agregar `promise.resolve()`.

```
mipromesa = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
$.ajax(
......
.......
  success: function(respuesta){
      //Muestro en pantalla el color guardado para ese usuario
      $('.colorSeleccionado').html(respuesta['color']);
      promise.resolve("completado");// se resulve la promera y se llama otra funcion
    }
  })
mipromesa.done(function(resultado){
//codigo
alert(resultado);
})
```

utilizando `then()` en vez de funcion luego de resolver la promesa

```
promise.then(function(exito){
   // nuevo ajax 
})
```

## otras formas de hacerlo:

## utilizando [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

```
function ajax(url,datos,cb){
  .......
  ........
  success: function(respuesta){
      cb(respuesta) //se llama al callback
    }

}
ajax("http://example.com",{'documento': documento},function(respuesta){
  ajax("http://example.com",{'documento': documento},function(respuesta){
    //codigo
  }
})
```

## con la api [**fecth**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch). donde `then` seria como `luego` mas limpio que utilizar promesas o callbacks

```
function ajax(url,datos){
 fetch('http://example.com')
  .then(function(response) { 
    return response.json(); // retona los datos en json
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson); // siguiente llamado a la funcion
  })
 .catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error.message);
 });
}
```

## utilizando [async y await](https://javascript.info/async-await).

ahora un ejemplo con todo:

```
async function ajax() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // espera hasta que se resuelva
}

ajax().then(function(){
 alert("se completo la ejecucion")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

asi seria con promise

```
function req1(){
  return new Promise ( (resolver,rechazar) => {
    var documento = $('.documento');

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('documento', documento);

    $.ajax({
    url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(respuesta){
      //Muestro en pantalla el color guardado para ese usuario
      $('.colorSeleccionado').html(respuesta['color']);
      resolver(respuesta); // AQUI VA EL RESOLVER

    },
    error:function(err){
      rechazar(err);
    }
  })
  });
}
```

asi seria el request dependiente

```
function req2(respTemp){
   var info = new FormData();

   info.append('color', respTemp['color']);

   $.ajax({
     url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
     method: 'POST',
     data: info,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(respuesta){
      console.log(respuesta) //Deberia mostrar la respuesta que retorne archivo.php
    }
  })
}
```

y las unes asi

```
req1().then( (rslt) => {
  req2(rslt);
}).catch( (err) => {
  console.log(err); // si la respuesta del ajax fue error y mando el "rechazar"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

en este caso yo utilizaría una funcion la cual recibe un parametro y luego usando ajax trae la información, es decir:

Seguimos tu proceso de evento click, el cual al recibir la respuesta, esta es entregada a la función para que procese la accion ajax y entre los datos correspondientes

```
$(".botonConsulta").click(function(){

//Capturo el número de documento de un input
  var documento = $('.documento');

  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append('documento', documento);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(respuesta){
      //Muestro en pantalla el color guardado para ese usuario
      $('.colorSeleccionado').html(respuesta['color']);

      //Llamamos a la función y entregamos el parámetro
      TraerDatos(respuesta['color']);

    }
  })
}

function TraerDatos(color){
    var info = new FormData();
    info.append('color', color);

    $.ajax({
         url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
         method: 'POST',
         data: info,
         dataType: 'json',
    success: function(respuesta){
           console.log(respuesta)
    });
}
```